# Hide data table automatically if there is no data to show

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have this simple data table:

```
<h:dataTable id="table1" value="#{fournisseurbean.BC.listematpilotaccess1}" style="width : 900px;  " var="item"
             border="1">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="idmatpilotaccess1n" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.idmatpilotaccess1}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="serie" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.serie}" />
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

I would like to not show this table if there is no data to show, so when 
`#{fournisseurbean.BC.listematpilotaccess1}` is empty. How can I achieve this?

Comment: 1) Java and JavaScript aren't the same thing 2) If I'm not mistaken, this is Java Server Faces

Comment: Does this table populates on page reload?

Comment: @BharathRallapalli yes!!!

Comment: You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505708/how-to-show-hide-datatables-by-selecting-values-from-drop-down-menu-in-jsf2-0-a) to improve your design and get a better understanding of the behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a rendered attribute to the tag

```
<h:dataTable rendered="#{not empty fournisseurbean.BC.listematpilotaccess1}">
```

This will render the component if the expression evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

render its ok but if you want to hide more than the datatble ,for example : a label or a div.
you can use :

```
<c:if test="#{beanMb.beanList.size() gt 0 }">
   ....code
 </c:if>
```